# Regex to extract a particular string and assign it to a variable

Tags: regex

I have following string :

```
Jul 20 16:47:43 chefawsdeveastbck2 dhclient[1036]: bound to 10.205.5.122 -- renewal in 1797 seconds.
Jul 17 18:07:15 chefawsdeveastbck2 Keepalived_vrrp[937]: VRRP_Instance(PC_VI) Sending gratuitous ARPs on eth0 for 10.205.5.121
Jul 17 18:07:10 chefawsdeveastbck2 Keepalived_vrrp[937]: VRRP_Instance(PC_VI) Sending gratuitous ARPs on eth0 for 10.205.5.121
Jul 17 18:07:10 chefawsdeveastbck2 Keepalived_vrrp[937]: VRRP_Instance(PC_VI) setting protocol VIPs.
Jul 17 18:07:10 chefawsdeveastbck2 Keepalived_vrrp[937]: VRRP_Instance(PC_VI) Entering MASTER STATE
Jul 17 18:07:09 chefawsdeveastbck2 Keepalived_vrrp[937]: VRRP_Instance(PC_VI) Transition to MASTER STATE
Jul 17 18:07:09 chefawsdeveastbck2 Keepalived_vrrp[937]: VRRP_Instance(PC_VI) Transition to Backup STATE
```

I only need to extract "MASTER STATE" , "backup STATE", "Backup STATE" from the above strings , which will always appear after "VRRP_Instance(PC_VI) Entering" or "VRRP_Instance(PC_VI) Transition to".
Right now , i have wrote the following:

```
.*(VRRP_Instance.*.[EnteringTransitionto]+ )(?P<instance_state>.+)
```

It obviously is not right and picking up other strings as well. Please help.

Comment: Just to clarify, the block of text -- is each line a separate string, or is the entire block one string?

Comment: Yes , each line is a separated string.

Comment: What language/tool are you using and what's your expected output?

Comment: I want to assign the value "MASTER STATE" and "Backup STATE" to a variable instance_state , for their respective lines . I am using Splunk tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use alternation to find your two possible key strings instead of trying to match any of the individual letters in them.

For example:

```
.*VRRP_Instance.*.(Entering|Transition to) (?P<instance_state>.+
```

Answer (score 1):

If **Master** and **Backup** states are the only states you have then you can use regex like this `((?:\bMASTER\b|\bBACKUP\b) STATE)$` with Multiline (m), Ignore case (i) and Global (g) modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

```
/VRRP_Instance\(PC_VI\) (?:Entering|Transition to) ((?:MASTER|[bB]ackup) STATE)/
```

[image: regexper diagram]